# shell variable with multiple values

Tags: shell-script, shell

this probably is very easy to do but I just can't get my head around it

I've got a script that grep some values from a file (file1)

sort of

```
var1=$(cat file1 | grep foo | grep bar)
```

if I echoed $var1 it would be a simple  word string like `string1`

997 out of 1000 times, var1 would be only 1 string, but then, there's a really small number of cases in which it has more than 1 string

```
string1 string2
```

how can I check if var1 has more than 1 string?

I've tried with `if [[ $var1 -gt "1" ]]` but obviously this is for integers

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it stores more than 1". Does it mean the content of `$var1` is a string containing several whitespace-separated "words"? Can you edit your question to present an example (i.e. the output of `echo $var1` for the "usual" and an assortment of "irregular" cases)?

Comment: `var1` will only ever store one value. It may be a value containing whitespace characters, but it will always be only one value because `var1` is a string, not a list.  It would be good to see examples of input and expected output.

Comment: edited, hopefully it will make it clearer

Comment: yes, I get the picture now

Comment: But do you mean space or newline? If there are two or more lines in `file1` containing both `bar` and `foo`, then your `var1` will contain newline characters. Is that what you are trying to detect? Or do you actually want to find cases where you have `foo bar` or `bar foo` instead of `foobar` or `barfoo`? It would be really helpful if you could add an example of the different kinds of input and output you get.

Comment: You can detect a non-word character in a variable with `if [[ $var1 =~ [^[:alnum:]_] ]]` or a space-like character with `if [[ $var1 =~ [[:space:]] ]]`.

Answer (score 0):

**May be this will help you to get the expected result**

```
var="$(grep 'foo' A.txt ) $(grep 'bar' A.txt)"
echo $var

count=`echo $var | wc -w`  
 
if [ $count -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "Contains only one string"
else
    echo "Contains more then one string"
fi
```

Comment: Note that `grep foo` and `grep bar` is not the same as `grep foo | grep bar`.  The former would get all lines containing either `foo` or `bar`, while the latter would get all lines containing both `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: @Kusalananda the value get override if file contains both the values  foo and bar               if i run this command :  `grep 'foo|bar' A.txt`  and where i run this command   `grep 'foo|bar' A.txt |  tr '\n' '\t'` it print both foo and bar as an Output in horizontal form. May be this is what the user want in one variable if found both values